# bootstrap modal opens unexpectedly on mouseenter

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I have a Bootstrap modal that is supposed to open on exit intent. For some reason, on the initial page load, it opens when the cursor enters the viewport. This is not the desired behavior. It should only open when the cursor leaves the viewport.

To be clear, the exit intent works as expected once you close the initial modal. I just can not figure out why the modal shows when the cursor first enters the viewport.

Here is the code:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://swamprabbitmedia.com/Sandbox/Exit-Modal/style.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
  <h2>20TH ANNIVERSARY SPECIAL!!!</h2>
 </div>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="exitModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">DON'T MISS OUT ON OUR 20TH ANNIVERSARY SPECIAL!!!</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
  <p>Save 20% on all residential carpet and upholstery cleaning!*</p>
  <img src="https://swamprabbitmedia.com/Sandbox/Exit-Modal/images/20-percent2.webp" />
  <p>* Valid for appointments booked through our office or online. Appointment must be booked for the month of April, 2023.</p>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">No Thanks</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="/contact/">Book Now</a></button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("body").mouseleave(function(){
            $("#exitModal").modal("show");
        });
        $("close").click(function(){
          $("#exitModal").modal({show: false});
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can prevent it?

You can view it live here: https://swamprabbitmedia.com/Sandbox/Exit-Modal/